# TFS: Work Item Email Notification Customisation

Tags: email, tfs

Our team of developers have started to use TFS version 16, and we're creating new Work Items (Bugs) and assigning them to appropriate parties. This is good, but it could be better. We've noticed the email is lacking some pretty useful stuff:

[Screenshot of current email alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLSu4.png)

It'd be great to add some more detail in the email, such as the severity of the bug, as to make sure whoever gets the email takes a look at it right away if needed. Are there any options in TFS to customize the Work Item alert email?

Comment: Actually is not any TFS is version 16. Take a look at this blog:[What version of Team Foundation Server do I have?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2013/11/21/what-version-of-team-foundation-server-do-i-have/) Are you using TFS2015 or TFS2017?

Answer (score 0):

No, its not possible to customize email alerts format in TFS/VSTS for now.

You could  try to create your own extension or use some 3rd-party extension  to handle this situation. Such as this [TfsNotificationRelay](https://github.com/kria/TfsNotificationRelay) include below features:

- Notify multiple targets
- Rule-based event filtering
- Regex filtering on collection, project, repository, branch etc.
- **Configurable notification format**
- Notification links back to event in TFS web
- Extensible to support other targets